# Not seeing System.ServiceModel.Syndication in .NET 3.5?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, .net-3.5, rss

I'm trying to implement an RssResult that derives from ActionResult in ASP.NET MVC 1 & .NET 3.5, following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11915/rss-feeds-in-asp-net-mvc). (There are some limitation on my company regarding the asp.net mvc framework, don't ask me why I'm still using it :)) Anyway, I couldn't find `System.ServiceModel.dll` in `C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.5` (it's in v3.0 and also in v4.0).

Am I missing something?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have .NET 3.5 installed, the `System.ServiceModel` (V3.0.0.0) assembly should be in the GAC. Reference it from there and you will see the [System.ServiceModel.Syndication namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.syndication%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) (you must have .NET 3.5 installed, the namespace is not available in .NET 3.0).

Comment: I do have .NET 3/3.5/4 frameworks installed. When I add the `System.ServiceModel` assembly to my project (.NET 3.5), I can't seems to find `System.ServiceModel.Syndication` namespace. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The best solution I found to this was [from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2667985/the-type-or-namespace-name-syndication-does-not-exist-in-the-namespace-system)

- **DOTNET 3.5**: add a reference to the System.ServiceModel.Web.dll
- **DOTNET 4.0**: add a reference to the System.ServiceModel.dll

It worked for me then.