# The Windows Phone Official Sample cannot even compile : Syndication misssing

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I tried to compile http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/gg266450

But it says It cannot find System.ServiceModel.Syndication

I have 2, 3.5, 4 .NET framework installed.

In add reference I can see System.ServiceModel and System.ServiceModel.Web version 2 not anything like 3 or 4 so I wonder how I could add that namespace as mentioned here
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.syndication.syndicationfeed(v=vs.95).aspx

This is rather incredible that MS has messed with namespaces and create examples that cannot even work. Other people did have same problem http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.syndication.syndicationfeed(v=vs.95).aspx

I confirm that MS has messed up by moving syndication from .net framework to silverlight sdk !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What was said in forum that doesn't fix the problem but finally I found another post that did fix the problem : Syndication is now in Silverlight SDK!

Comment: As per MSDN on references for the SyndicationFeed Class:

Assembly:  System.ServiceModel (in System.ServiceModel.dll)

Answer (score 3):

- DOTNET 3.5: add a reference to the System.ServiceModel.Web.dll
- DOTNET 4.0: add a reference to the System.ServiceModel.dll

This will fix your missing Syndication exception.

Comment: No as I said that's was said in forum that doesn't fix the problem but finally I found another post that did fix the problem : Syndication is now in Silverlight SDK!